# What is wrong with this SimPy installation?

Tags: python, windows, installation, simpy

Alright, I have tried a bunch of times the

```
python setup.py install
```

command from my command prompt

And when trying this:

```
from SimPy.Simulation import *
```

on Idle, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python30/pruebas/prueba1", line 1, in <module>
    from SimPy.Simulation import *
  File "C:\Python30\SimPy\Simulation.py", line 320
    print 'SimPy.Simulation %s' %__version__,
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every module supports python 3 - in fact, 90% or more of the modules are for 2.x now.

you should use 2.5 or 2.6 for this module, or find a simpy  that is compatible with 3.0.

you can also run the 2->3 upgrade script to modify your simpy source, but I don't suggest doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar error, and I Installed python 2.6.4, so I don't think you can solve your problem using an older version of python.

```
alumno@ubuntu:/usr/local/SimPy/SimPy$ python carro.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "carro.py", line 2, in <module>

from SimPy.Simulation  import *

ImportError: No module named SimPy.Simulation
```

Python 2.6.4rc2 (r264rc2:75497, Oct 20 2009, 02:55:11) 
[GCC 4.4.1] on linux2

Answer (score 0):

Refer point 4 of:
 http://pythonhosted.org/SimPy/Manuals/INSTALLATION.html
for a workaround. It worked for me.

simpy package does not seem to have same classes as SimPy by using pip install SimPy command, simpy gets installed.

Hence, just download the SimPy package from the link and copy it to your classpath for python.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your Python installation. SimPy 1 and SimPy 2 use remarkably different syntax from SimPy 3, which is the version that you have installed - and the one which is widely available. The old tutorials are all written in view of the old SimPy versions. Checkout this page...

http://simpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/simpy_intro/installation.html